# Bat file to run a .exe at the command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe

I want to create a .bat file so I can just click on it so it can run:

```
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service
```

Can someone help me with the structure of the .bat file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a program from a batch file without leaving the console open after the program start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324539/how-can-i-run-a-program-from-a-batch-file-without-leaving-the-console-open-after)

Answer (score 242):

To start a program and then close command prompt without waiting for program to exit:

```
start /d "path" file.exe
```

Comment: @MehdiJ: sets home directory.

Comment: its possible to run the bat file from web browser? like a javascript to call the bat file ??

Comment: @Karthi: sorry, it's impossible

Comment: @Karthi You do not want javascript to be able to run a bat file for security reasons.

Comment: how do you wait for the program to exit?

Comment: @m4l490n you can use /wait. For example: start /wait "c:\windows\system32" notepad.exe

Answer (score 70):

You can use:

```
start "windowTitle" fullPath/file.exe
```

Note: the first set of quotes must be there but you don't have to put anything in them, e.g.:

```
start "" fullPath/file.exe
```

Comment: The 'first set of quotes' is merely the window title and is NOT required.  It is however, best to specify the startup directory using /d

`start /d "fullpath" file.exe`

This ensures any dependent files are, e.g. a DLL, are found and loaded.

Answer (score 47):

it is very simple code for executing notepad 
bellow code type into a notepad and save to extension .bat  Exapmle:notepad.bat

```
start "c:\windows\system32" notepad.exe
```

(above code "c:\windows\system32" is path where you kept your .exe program and notepad.exe is your .exe program file file)

enjoy!

Answer (score 31):

Just put that line in the bat file...

Alternatively you can even make a shortcut for svcutil.exe, then add the arguments in the 'target' window.

Answer (score 9):

Just stick in a file and call it "ServiceModelSamples.bat" or something.

You could add "@echo off" as line one, so the command doesn't get printed to the screen:

```
@echo off
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service
```

Comment: And instead of adding an `@echo off` as first line, you could simply add `@` at beginning of line you don't want to be echoed...

Answer (score 8):

A bat file has no structure...it is how you would type it on the command line. So just open your favourite editor..copy the line of code you want to run..and save the file as whatever.bat or whatever.cmd

Answer (score 7):

If you want to be real smart, at the command line type:

```
echo svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service >CreateService.cmd
```

Then you have `CreateService.cmd` that you can run whenever you want (`.cmd` is just another extension for `.bat` files)

Answer (score 6):

What's stopping you?

Put this command in a text file, save it with the .bat (or .cmd) extension and double click on it...

Presuming the command executes on your system, I think that's it.

Answer (score 4):

As described [here](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html), about the `Start` command, the following would start your application with the parameters you've specified:

```
start "svcutil" "svcutil.exe" "language:cs" "out:generatedProxy.cs" "config:app.config" "http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service"
```

- `"svcutil"`, after the `start` command, is the name given to the CMD window upon running the application specified. This is a required parameter of the `start` command.
- `"svcutil.exe"` is the absolute or relative path to the application you want to run. Using quotation marks allows you to have spaces in the path.
- After the application to start has been specified, all the following parameters are interpreted as arguments sent to the application.

Answer (score 3):

If your folders are set to "hide file extensions", you'll name the file *.bat or *.cmd and it will still be a text file (hidden .txt extension).  Be sure you can properly name a file!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the important point it seems here is that svcutil is not available by default from command line, you can run it from the vs xommand line shortcut but if you make a batch file normally that wont help unless you run the vcvarsall.bat file before the script.
Below is a sample

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio *version*\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service
```