# Run an app from bat file and continue program

Tags: batch-file, blender

I have the following .bat code:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender"
blender.exe
image.jpeg
```

I am trying to make blender open when I start the batch file, then immediately after, show image called "image.jpeg"

When I do this, it starts blender in the current `cmd` window, and then holds the program up until blender is closed.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a program from a batch file without leaving the console open after the program starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324539/how-can-i-run-a-program-from-a-batch-file-without-leaving-the-console-open-after) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451861/how-to-not-wait-for-a-process-to-complete-in-batch-script or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937569/how-to-start-an-application-without-waiting-in-a-batch-file or many more

Comment: You may use `start` command: `start blender.exe`, probably you may be interested in `/B` key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to NOT wait for a process to complete in batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451861/how-to-not-wait-for-a-process-to-complete-in-batch-script)

Comment: @underscore_d Though I agree that `start` is the solution here, I do not really agree with the solutions of the linked answers themselves. the way `start` is used in those examples may work, but they are incorrect. `start` sees the first quoted object as the title, so `start "c:\program files\someprog.exe"` might end up in certain cases not working. The correct method is `start "" "C:\Program files\someprog.exe"`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard One of the questions I linked is very careful to point that out in its top answer, and the others end up mentioning it somewhere.

Comment: Are you wanting to open `image.jpeg` in `blender.exe`? or are you wanting to open `blender.exe` and also open the default application assigned to `.jpeg` files with `image.jpeg` showing. Also your code suggests that `image.jpeg` is located inside the directory `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender`. Please provide us with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `start` does that for you This assumes `image.jpg` is in the same directory as blender:

```
cd /d "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender"
start "" "blender.exe"
image.jpeg
```

same with this:

```
pushd "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender"
start "" "blender.exe"
image.jpeg
popd
```

where this assumes `image.jpeg` is in the folder where the batch file started from:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\Blender.exe"
image.jpeg
```