# set batch script for loop to NOT wait for previous iteration to complete

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have the following script which launches multiple sessions of RDP connection files at once (colleted from a folder which only contains rdp files).

If I launch **this** from cmd prompt, **it launches all sessions in parallel** (*which is what I want*)

```
for /r %i in (*.rdp) do (mstsc %~nxi /f)
```

**while **if i run **this** script, **it just launches the first session then waits for the relative process to end before running the second connection** and so on.

```
for /r %%i in (*.rdp) do (mstsc %%~nxi /f)
```

**What I'm doing wrong?** Shouldn't it be the default behavior of batch to run all commands in parallel?

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451861/how-to-not-wait-for-a-process-to-complete-in-batch-script) but it doesn't address my exact scenario and it doesn't work anyhow as expected (e.g. START myBatchScript.bat doens't change the "waiting for process" behavior)

**EDIT**
Added answer based on comments *(Thanks to @Compo and @Modi)*

Comment: Perhaps ```@for /r %i in (*.rdp) do @(start "" mstsc "%~nxi" /f)```

Comment: thank you that works. also in this formulation `for /r %%i in (*.rdp) do (start "" mstsc %%~nxi /f)`

Comment: Please keep the doublequotes, they give protection for possible spaces and  other problematic characters in the file names.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on why the behavior differs between running it in cmd vs batch file?

Comment: Directly in [[tag:cmd]] you'd use ```for /r %i in (*.rdp) do @(start "" mstsc "%~nxi" /f)```. The difference being in a [[tag:batch-file]] the `%`, characters need escaping with another, i.e. `@for /r %%i in (*.rdp) do @(start "" mstsc "%%~nxi" /f)`.

Comment: notation is clear, thanks; with my question I meant if you have any idea why running `for /r %i in (*.rdp) do (mstsc %~nxi /f)` directly in cmd launches all rdp sessions at the same time while running `for /r %%i in (*.rdp) do (mstsc %%~nxi /f)` as batch files runs the sessions one at a time awaiting the closure of the previous one before running the subsequent.
If you want to replicate this just create a folder with more than one txt file and try launching `for /r %i in (*.txt) do (notepad %~nxi)` from cmd vs `for /r %%i in (*.txt) do (notepad %%~nxi)` as a batch file

Comment: @Deozzissimo When a Windows __GUI__ executable like `%SystemRoot%\System32\mstsc.exe` (fully qualified file name recommended in batch file) is started directly from within a command prompt window, `cmd.exe` starts it as separate running process so that the user can switch back to the command prompt window, for example with __Alt+TAB__ and immediately execute the next internal command of `cmd` or another executable.

Comment: @Deozzissimo Only if there is run a Windows __console__ executable from within a command prompt window, `cmd.exe` starts it with waiting for self-termination of this executable which is using the standard input/output/error streams of `cmd.exe` and so also the console window of `cmd`. For more information about starting an executable please read the Microsoft documentation of the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw).

Comment: @Deozzissimo The meaning of the word __batch__ in *__batch__* file is running one command/executable after the other. The Windows Command Processor starts on processing a batch file every executable independent on being an application with a graphical user interface or a console application with waiting for self-termination of the started executable before opening the batch file again, reading the next line(s), parsing the line(s), closing the batch file and executing the next line(s). The internal command `start` of `cmd.exe` is for changing the default behavior on starting an executable.

Comment: @Deozzissimo `start /wait` can be used directly in a command prompt window to start a Windows GUI executable and let `cmd.exe` wait until the user exits the GUI application. Just `start` can be used in a batch file to start an executable (GUI or console application) to run it as separate process parallel to `cmd.exe` which immediately continues with batch file processing (the `for` loop in your case) after calling `CreateProcess`. If you run `start /?` in a cmd window, read the output usage help and have read the `CreateProcess` documentation as well as the documentation page for the ...

Comment: @Deozzissimo ... [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure also carefully, you should notice that all options of `start` control parameters of `CreateProcess` or values in the `STARTUPINFO` structure. `CreateProcess` is used by nearly any other Windows executable capable starting another Windows executable like `explorer.exe`, `powershell.exe`, `cscript.exe` and `wscript.exe`, etc. The properties of a shortcut file (`.lnk`) are also more clear after reading the docs about `CreateProcess` and `STARTUPINFO`.

Answer (score 1):

The coding solution to replicate the cmd behavior as a batch script is using the "start" command (as below, thanks to @Compo)

`@for /r %i in (*.rdp) do @(start "" mstsc "%~nxi" /f)`

for the reason *why* this happens refer to @Mofi comments.