# CALL command vs. START with /WAIT option

Tags: windows, batch-file

How is the START command with a WAIT option

```
START /wait notepad.exe 
START /wait  notepad.exe
```

...any different from using a CALL command?

```
CALL notepad.exe 
CALL notepad.exe
```

Is there a situation where one may behave differently that the other dependending on what is being executed?

Comment: Take a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx is about START and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490873.aspx is about CALL

Answer (score 230, accepted):

For *exe* files, I suppose the differences are nearly unimportant.
But to start an *exe* you don't even need `CALL`.

When starting another batch it's a big difference,
as `CALL` will start it in the same window and the called batch has access  to the same variable context.
So it can also change variables which affects the caller.

`START` will create a new cmd.exe for the called batch and without /b it will open a new window.
As it's a new context, variables can't be shared.

## Differences

**Using `start /wait <prog>`**
- Changes of environment variables are lost when the `<prog>` ends
- The caller waits until the `<prog>` is finished

**Using `call <prog>`**
- For *exe* it can be ommited, because it's equal to just starting `<prog>`
- For an *exe-prog* the caller batch waits or starts the *exe* asynchronous, but the behaviour depends on the *exe* itself.
- For *batch* files, the caller batch continues, when the called `<batch-file>` finishes, WITHOUT call the control will not return to the caller batch

## Addendum:

Using `CALL` can change the parameters (for batch and exe files), but only when they contain carets or percent signs.

```
call myProg param1 param^^2 "param^3" %%path%%
```

Will be expanded to (from within an batch file)

```
myProg param1 param2 param^^3 <content of path>
```

Comment: When executing a file.bat using START /WAIT you need to specify START /WAIT cmd /c "file.bat" rather than just START /WAIT "file.bat", else the cmd window created for file.bat will remain open

Comment: You can find the comparison between CALL and START at:

https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

(updated today with sections "Start /Wait" and "START vs CALL")

Comment: My favourite is `start /wait /b cmd /c <batchfile.bat>` because the batch files run one after the other in the same command window

Comment: @linux64kb, But for batch files it's not necessary, you only need `call batchfile.bat`

Comment: @jeb True. I prefer this one because each batch file will run in a different command shell enviroment, inheriting variables from the calling shell and changes to the initial values will be lost after the batch finished -> no garbage left there after each consecutive run. Another win is, that you don't have to deal with resetting variables in your scripts.

Comment: Doesn't "setlocal" do that for you?

Comment: Also remember that if you're using a quoted path, include a quoted window title first, like `start "My Batch File 2" "C:\Batch Files\batchfile2.bat"` otherwise it will interpret your quoted path as the window title and not work.

Comment: yes, @gami - this is a difference: `start /wait "path\myProg"` opens a new command windows with title "path\myProg" (because of the quotes) while `call "path\myProg"` really calls myProg.exe.

Answer (score 22):

I think that they should perform generally the same, but there are some differences.
`START` is generally used to start applications or to start the default application for a given file type.  That way if you `START http://mywebsite.com` it doesn't do `START iexplore.exe http://mywebsite.com`.

`START myworddoc.docx` would start Microsoft Word and open myworddoc.docx.`CALL myworddoc.docx` does the same thing... however `START` provides more options for the window state and things of that nature. It also allows process priority and affinity to be set.

In short, given the additional options provided by start, it should be your tool of choice.

```
START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
  [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
  [/NODE <NUMA node>] [/AFFINITY <hex affinity mask>] [/WAIT] [/B]
  [command/program] [parameters]

"title"     Title to display in window title bar.
path        Starting directory.
B           Start application without creating a new window. The
            application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
            enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
            the application.
I           The new environment will be the original environment passed
            to the cmd.exe and not the current environment.
MIN         Start window minimized.
MAX         Start window maximized.
SEPARATE    Start 16-bit Windows program in separate memory space.
SHARED      Start 16-bit Windows program in shared memory space.
LOW         Start application in the IDLE priority class.
NORMAL      Start application in the NORMAL priority class.
HIGH        Start application in the HIGH priority class.
REALTIME    Start application in the REALTIME priority class.
ABOVENORMAL Start application in the ABOVENORMAL priority class.
BELOWNORMAL Start application in the BELOWNORMAL priority class.
NODE        Specifies the preferred Non-Uniform Memory Architecture (NUMA)
            node as a decimal integer.
AFFINITY    Specifies the processor affinity mask as a hexadecimal number.
            The process is restricted to running on these processors.

            The affinity mask is interpreted differently when /AFFINITY and
            /NODE are combined.  Specify the affinity mask as if the NUMA
            node's processor mask is right shifted to begin at bit zero.
            The process is restricted to running on those processors in
            common between the specified affinity mask and the NUMA node.
            If no processors are in common, the process is restricted to
            running on the specified NUMA node.
WAIT        Start application and wait for it to terminate.
```

Answer (score 14):

There is a useful difference between `call` and `start /wait` when calling `regsvr32.exe /s` for example, also referenced by [Gary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236365/gary) in 
in his answer to [how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)

```
call regsvr32.exe /s broken.dll
echo %errorlevel%
```

will always return 0 but

```
start /wait regsvr32.exe /s broken.dll
echo %errorlevel%
```

will return the error level from regsvr32.exe

Answer (score 10):

This is what I found while running batch files in parallel (multiple instances of the same bat file at the same time with different input parameters) :

Lets say that you have an exe file that performs a long task called 
LongRunningTask.exe

If you call the exe directly from the bat file, only the first call to the LongRunningTask will succed, while the rest will get an OS error "File is already in use by the process"

If you use this command:

start /B /WAIT "" "LongRunningTask.exe" "parameters"

You will be able to run multiple instances of the bat and exe, while still waiting for the task to finish before the bat continues executing the remaining commands. The /B option is to avoid creating another window, the empty quotes are needed in order to the command to work, see the reference below.

Note that if you don´t use the /WAIT in the start, the LongRunningTask will be executed at the same time than the remaining commands in the batch file, so it might create problems if one of these commands requires the output of the LongRunningTask

Resuming :

This can´t run in parallel :

- call LongRunningTask.exe

This will run in parallel and will be ok as far as there are no data dependencies between the output of the command and the rest of the bat file :

- start /B "" "LongRunningTask.exe" "parameters"

This will run in parallel and wait for the task to finish, so you can use the output :

- start /B /WAIT "" "LongRunningTask.exe" "parameters"

Reference for the start command : [How can I run a program from a batch file without leaving the console open after the program start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324539/how-can-i-run-a-program-from-a-batch-file-without-leaving-the-console-open-after)

Answer (score 9):

**Call**

Calls one batch program from another **without stopping the parent batch program.** The call command accepts labels as the target of the call. Call has no effect at the command-line when used outside of a script or batch file.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490873.aspx

**Start**

Starts a **separate Command Prompt window** to run a specified program or command. Used without parameters, start opens a second command prompt window.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx