# TortoiseSVN batch file output info

Tags: batch-file, svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to do the equivalent of the following Linux command with a Windows batch file and TortoiseSVN.

```
svn info > info.txt
```

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
start /wait "" "c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:info >> %CD%\info.txt
```

I am running Windows with TortoiseSVN v1.6.16 so I don't have access to the command line tools.

Note: We were encountering issues with the newer version of TortoiseSVN so we went back to 1.6 until issues are resolved with a newer version and the company upgrades the server to that version.

Comment: Put the empty string `""` _before_ the `/WAIT` switch...

Comment: TortoiseSVN comes with a version of SVN to use at the command line. What's wrong with `%ProgramFiles%\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe info > info.txt`? Or if TortoiseSVN is in your PATH (which it is by default) just `svn info > info.txt`?

Comment: @ken v1.6 doesn't have the command line tools. v1.8 did but we had issues with that version

Comment: @pcnate did you try version 1.7?

Comment: @Squashman haven't been given the choice of the version since I'm not an admin on site...

Comment: @pcnate then put pressure on the admins to get things upgraded. Having current *and supported* tools is important. And 1.9.x clients will still work perfectly fine with older servers. Even if you have to use TortoiseSVN 1.8, it'll be an improvement.

Comment: Bizarre! And it's amateur WASP. OMFG, miserable USA!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construction didn't work, doesn't work and will never work due to zero-bits of trueness:

- `start` (with and without `/wait`) have sense in bat-file only if you have more than one bat-process starting from *this* bat ([compare with `call`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257571/call-command-vs-start-with-wait-option)), for called GUI it doesn't differ from direct using program-name
- TortoiseProc is GUI-app after all, it emits **nothing** to stdout
- Info was and is unknown [command for TortoiseProc](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html), thus you'll get only GUI-window "About"

> :about    Shows the about dialog. This is also **shown if no command is
>   given**

In addition to correct suggestion "Update to at least 1.8 on client and have CLI-tools" you can consider following solutions:

- Install from unrelated to TortoiseSVN sources pure CLI SVN-client (also 1.6.* - from WanDisco will be good choice) at the same as TSVN or another location (I done it at the times of 1.6)
- Study and use [subwcrev](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) (it was part of TortoiseSVN even in 1.6, AFAICR) and emulate some part of `svn info` in subwcrev's template-file with correct keywords

Comment: 1.8 was broken for us, I am going to wait until corp will get us 1.9 and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately version 1.9 also hangs with a timeout. What the heck is going on with SVN 1.8+?