# Cannot get exit code when running subprocesses in python using Popen and start /wait

Tags: python, windows, command-line, popen, exit-code

I'm trying to create a python script that starts a new window and waits for it to complete, and then retrieve the exit code.  So I am using Popen with `start /wait` to create a separate window for it, but this does not properly forward the exit code.

This code summarizes the problem:

```
import subprocess

params = {}
params['stdout'] = subprocess.PIPE
params['stderr'] = subprocess.PIPE
params['shell'] = True

proc = subprocess.Popen('start /wait cmd /c exit 1', **params)

# This works but the above line does not
#proc = subprocess.Popen('exit 1', **params)

resultCode = proc.wait()

print(resultCode)
```

The documentation for `start /wait` suggests that it should return the exit code, and when I run it manually and then check `%ERRORLEVEL%` it appears correct, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @OferSadan I've updated the code to remove unnecessary imports and problem persists

Comment: I have tried to replicate it with both types of imports and I get the same results as you, so apologies for the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMD's `start` command always succeeds overall if it successfully executes the given command via `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecuteEx`. It succeeds even if it's instructed to `/wait` and ends up setting `%errorlevel%` to a non-zero value. You can see this by running `(start /wait exit 1) && echo success`. The `&&` operator only executes the right-hand expression if the left-hand expression succeeds.

To work around this, you can manually exit the initial shell using the `!errorlevel!` value that gets set by `start`. For example:

```py
command = 'exit 1'
shell_path = os.environ.get('ComSpec', 'cmd.exe')
start_command = 'start "" /wait {}'.format(command)
cmdline = '"{shell}" /v:on /c "({command}) & exit !errorlevel!"'.format(
          shell=shell_path, command=start_command)

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note that the above `Popen` call does not use the `shell=True` argument because the shell needs to be run manually with the `/v:on` option. This enables delayed expansion of environment variables, using "!" instead of "%".

That said, you don't need the shell for your stated objective. Simply have the child process create a new console by passing the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` creation flag as follows:

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('call cmd /c exit 1', **params)
```

Instead of your `start /wait` returns the error code 1 in `resultCode`.

By the logic of this question and answer: [CALL command vs. START with /WAIT option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257571/call-command-vs-start-with-wait-option)

My guess would be that the difference is that `start /wait` doesn't share variables with the same environment and `call` does.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution that opens up a separate command line window which does not happen when using CALL