# Is there a way to configure OpenAPI Generator to run synchronously?

Tags: asynchronous, openapi-generator

I am trying to the following in a bat file, in Windows, using [OpenAPI generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/):

```
openapi-generator generate -i open-api-offline-file.json -g csharp-netcore -c open-api-config.json -o DataLakeOpenApiRestClient 

REM customizing ApiClient
xcopy .\SourcesCustomizations\ApiClient.cs .\DataLakeOpenApiRestClient\src\Org.OpenAPITools\Client\ApiClient.cs* /Y /F /R
```

This only generates the code without running the second command (or it is run before the generation ends).

If I start the generation with `start /wait`:

```
start /wait openapi-generator generate -i open-api-offline-file.json -g csharp-netcore -c open-api-config.json -o DataLakeOpenApiRestClient 

REM customizing ApiClient
xcopy .\SourcesCustomizations\ApiClient.cs .\DataLakeOpenApiRestClient\src\Org.OpenAPITools\Client\ApiClient.cs* /Y /F /R
```

it kind of works as expected (explicitly starts a new process and waits for it to exit).

**Question:** Is there a way to configure OpenAPI Generator to run synchronously?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CALL command vs. START with /WAIT option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257571/call-command-vs-start-with-wait-option)

Comment: The 2nd example with `start /wait` is the correct solution. It's a Windows thing.