# Is it possible hide the console window of a JXCore packaged exe?

Tags: windows, console, jxcore

I've successfully packaged an exe application using JXCore

But, since such application will be called from another app, I need that when executed, the window console shouldn't appear

Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324539/how-can-i-run-a-program-from-a-batch-file-without-having-the-console-open-after

Answer (score 0):

This is not natively supported yet, but you may want to check the discussion [Run executable in the background](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/issues/159) on that subject.

Someone made a VBS script for this, while someone else wrapped the app.exe into windows-service-like tool.