# run the PHP buit-in web server from file cmd

Tags: php, windows, server

I often use the PHP built-in server from CMD (windows) with: `php -S 127.0.0.2:8000`

But, I want to create a CMD File, which I just double click to run the server.
I tried with : `exec`, `chell_exec`, system but it doesn't work.

Comment: run the server or run a PHP-script on the sever?

Comment: ahhhh I think I get your intention. Batch-File: start "absolut path of php.exe" -S 127.0.0.2:8000 (writen from my memories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a batch programm.
Take a look on these sources:

[[1]](https://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Batch-File)
[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324539/how-can-i-run-a-program-from-a-batch-file-without-leaving-the-console-open-after#15549987)

How to do it:

- create a file e.g. yourbatch.bat
- add following line: `php -S 127.0.0.2:8000` or `start php -S 127.0.0.2:8000`
- save
- double click your file