# How to execute c# console application from batch file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, batch-file, console-application

I have the sample console application which is supposed to be executed in the startup task, i want to execute the console application through batch file, please can i know the right syntax to execute it.

Comment: Console application is like usual exe files, you can use "Call ConsoleApp.exe" ConsoleApp will be your application name

Comment: This thread discussed on the same:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221730/bat-file-to-run-a-exe-at-the-command-prompt

Comment: Why exactly is the question downvoted? It's clearly stated and it's unreasonable to expect any sample code in this case. I remember having the exact same problem some 21 years ago (well, not with C#).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"C:\Users\mahesh\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\Foo\bin\Debug\Foo.exe"
Foo
Foo.exe
"\Some other folder\foo"
```

would all be possible options how to execute it, depending on where the program resides and what your current working directory is ...

Answer (score 2):

just put the full path of the console application .exe file in the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

In my project .

Folder is like

```
D:\Run
│  main.bat  >> your batch file
│  
└─Test
    │  
    │  
    └─your application
```

Content of the bat file is like

```
cd /d %~dp0test\
Checker.exe>check.log
```

The first line

`cd /d %~dp0test\`

is replace the runtime directory to the full path of the appliction file.

```
>check.log
```

Is an option to output the log file.