# How to run an EXE when another exe is running?

Tags: file, dll, batch-file, exe

How do I make an exe run automatically when another exe is launched?

Example :

EXE 1 is launched & running

EXE 2 will run automatically once it see that the EXE 1 has already launched.

What is the command do I use in .bat file or autorun.inf?

Comment: sorry I meant i need the exe 2 to run ONLY if exe is running, so is there some command to say for example, if exe 1 is running, run exe 2 automatically. if i use the command bellow this will just run both same time which i dont want to do, i want exe 2 to run only if its see that exe 1 is running in the Windows Task Manager under processes. thanks

Comment: @ Bali C. Thank you so much this works but only problem i need when example exe1.exe runs for exe2.exe to run thats without CLICKING on the batch . the above code works perfect only if i click on the batch. is there a way to make exe2.exe run automatically IF somehow the exe1.exe is running WITHOUT  having to click on the batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
start exe1.exe
:LOOP
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq exe1.exe" | find /i "exe1.exe" >nul && start exe2.exe || goto :LOOP
```

That will start `exe1.exe` and will keep looking to see if it has started before running `exe2.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
START /D "path" myexe1.exe
START /D "path" myexe3.exe
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221730/bat-file-to-run-a-exe-at-the-command-prompt).

Then save the file as "somename.bat"

**Edit**

Due to your last comment here's what I [found](http://www.instructables.com/answers/Check-if-a-process-is-running-from-a-batch-file/)

```
@echo off
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq chrome.exe" | find /i "chrome.exe" >nul && (
    echo Windows Media Player is running
) || (
    echo Chrome is not running
)
pause>nul
```

I just copied the code from the link, google can be very helpful.