# GCP Compute Engine WS 2012. Startup script dont run my .exe file after boot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, startupscript

My GCP Compute Engine instance running WS 2012 does not execute an executable command while using using  a startup script.

Summary of steps followed:

1. I created a Compute Engine instance with WS 2012.
2. Set Metadata keys `windows-startup-script-cmd` with value = `"c:/prog/1.exe".
3. copied all needed files to local disk.(exact folder c:/prog/).
4. Shut down VM. (by GCP console).
5. Started instance from the GCP console.

And it seems that the command "c:/prog/1.exe" did not run

I saw "1.exe" process running in the Task Manager but it did not do anything . (It should have created a specific file to show that it ran successfully).

Please, tell me if I did something wrong, Or if I missed anything.
Thanks for your help .

Comment: Well start up script is working but application don't. It's because some sort of permissions but i dont know how to permit this.

Answer (score 0):

The `windows-startup-script-cmd` is metadata key to run `cmd startup scripts` on Windows instances. The `cmd startup scripts` are those with `.cmd` or `.bat` extensions. You can run your executable files through a batch file. How? visit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221730/bat-file-to-run-a-exe-at-the-command-prompt?answertab=votes#tab-top) on stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry! Ok. This is trying to work. BUT! Application cant run. It's all because "The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID" problem. I know how to fix it: just by giving permission to a user. BUT I cant edit registry. It throw security window with "Unable to save permissions changes".