# running ffmpeg.exe from inside bash file

Tags: windows, bash, ffmpeg, command-prompt

Hello I am trying to run ffmpeg from inside a `track_cmd.sh` file which I run inside command prompt using the command `bash track_cmd.sh`
My file looks like this:

```
echo "try1"
C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\jan2023-rendertune\RenderTune\node_modules\ffmpeg-ffprobe-static\ffmpeg.exe
echo "try2"
# start /d "path" file.exe
start /d "C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\jan2023-rendertune\RenderTune\node_modules\ffmpeg-ffprobe-static" ffmpeg.exe
echo "try3"
# start "c:\windows\system32" notepad.exe   
start "C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\jan2023-rendertune\RenderTune\node_modules\ffmpeg-ffprobe-static" ffmpeg.exe   
echo "try4"
#start "" fullPath/file.exe
start "" C:\\Users\\marti\\Documents\\projects\\jan2023-rendertune\\RenderTune\\node_modules\\ffmpeg-ffprobe-static\\ffmpeg.exe
echo "done"
```

But none of these lines work:

```
>bash track_cmd.sh
try1
track_cmd.sh: line 2: C:UsersmartiDocumentsprojectsjan2023-rendertuneRenderTunenode_modulesffmpeg-ffprobe-staticffmpeg.exe: command not found
try2
track_cmd.sh: line 5: start: command not found
try3
track_cmd.sh: line 8: start: command not found
try4
track_cmd.sh: line 11: start: command not found
done
```

I have tried the examples posted in this question:
[Bat file to run a .exe at the command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221730/bat-file-to-run-a-exe-at-the-command-prompt)

But none work. If I run the command `C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\jan2023-rendertune\RenderTune\node_modules\ffmpeg-ffprobe-static\ffmpeg.exe` inside command prompt, I get ffmpeg, so I know the path works.

Comment: [tag:batch-file] and [tag:bash] are not the same thing, and they do not use the same syntax! What interpreter are you using on your Windows system?

Comment: I don't think the duplicate is correct; I simply voted to close as uncelar.